# why i am getting wrong path with compass sprite

Tags: compass-sass, css-sprites

With compass when i am trying to create a sprite the path of the main sprite image in screen.css is going wrong because of which i can't see the image.

My scss code is

```
@import "compass";
@import "spr/*.png";
 h1 { @include spr-sprite("car");  height:50px; width:50px; }
```

My css output for sprite

```
.spr-sprite, h1 {  background: url('/images/spr-sa37328aec0.png') no-repeat; }
h1 {  background-position: 0 -147px;  
height: 50px; 
width: 50px;
overflow: hidden; 
text-align: left; 

                  }
```

You can see that the out of the background should be started with `../` but not directly with the `/images/`. Its creating a problem.
My folder paths for images

```
images
 ------spr
          ---*.png
sass
-----screen.scss
css
---screen.css
```

My config.rb codes

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Am new to sass and compass, so may be i am missing some code. Please help me to find it out.
 Any help will be greatly appreciated. Very Very Thanks in Advance to repliers.

Comment: Where is you compiled style sheet in relation to the images folder?

Comment: My style sheet is outside the images folder. I think its default how compass actually create project. (images,sass,styleheets,config.rb)

Comment: Might be helpful to see your `config.rb` file. Something set in the [Configuration options](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) is out of whack with your project structure.

Comment: config.rb code updated. Please see up

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to your `config.rb`:

```
relative_assets = true
```

(I'm assuming that you're not serving this from the root of a domain, otherwise it shouldn't be needed. Are you viewing the page(s) via `file://`?)